# UIGesture ignore all transparent areas

Tags: ios, swift

Imagine a transparent frame, like an image frame, as a `UIImageview` and a text view in the middle.

The user see a frame and a text in the middle, but if he try to touch the text, he think he touch the text, but he may touch the frame if it's **z position is on top**.

I am looking for a way to "see" touches from `GestureRecognizer`, as the actual pixel that you touch.

So if the frame is on top, in terms of software it covers the text, but the user see the text and try to touch it, but instead the frame will recieve it.

Is there a way to "follow" the actual pixels, and receive the touches **as you see them** 
 and **not** as their containers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specified the location in certain view of your gesture recognizer.

Suppose I have a view containing a button(UIView).

- View

  - My Button

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addGesture()
    }

    private func addGesture() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    @objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location sender.location(in: view) 
        for subview in view {
            if subview.frame.contains(location) {
               // check whether this view is what you wanted? (by tag or something else...) 
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my view is dynamic, I don't know what is going to be on top of what, it's a working area , you can drag things around, and add more things etc. So having said that, you must be able to respond to what you "See" , where the actual pixles, where you think you touched :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't know whether it could help you.